# Валидация пароля на наличие букв идущих в алфавитном порядке

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Всем привет!

Есть необходимость валидировать пароли на наличие букв идущих в алфавитном порядке.

Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобными задачами ранее и знает какой-нибудь оптимальный вариант.

Может есть какие-нибудь готовые библиотеки, которые могут делать что-то подобное.
Не хочется просто свой велосипед придумывать.

Любые подсказки/советы приветствуются.

Comment: Только букв? А с цифрами что? 123456?

Comment: @aepot, только букв.

Comment: Убивал бы всех авторов валидаторов паролей. Если я устанавливаю пароль `123` значит мне не важно то, что этот пароль защищает и мой выбор пароля - это осознанное действие

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, оффтоп конечно с вашей стороны, но прокомментирую. Сегодня вы ставите пароль 123 на проде, а завтра база с прода уже лежит в открытом доступе в сети. Последствия думаю всем понятны.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov к счастью этот валидатор 123 пропустит. :)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, для пароля 123 будут другие валидаторы, сейчас речь идёт про алфавит.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov https://humor.rin.ru/cgi-bin/show.pl?razdel=0&anekdot=30126

Comment: @Harry Ну это классика

Comment: @AntonShchyrov От этого она не становится менее актуальной :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кажется, вы слегка перемудрили. Не нужно хранить алфавит, вам же только последовательность следующий-предыдущий обрабатывать, так?

```cs
private static bool IsValidPassword(string password, int maxCharsInOrderCount)
{
    if (password == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException($"{nameof(password)} был null");
    if (maxCharsInOrderCount < 2)
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(maxCharsInOrderCount)} должно быть больше, чем 1");
    if (password.Length < maxCharsInOrderCount)
        return true;

    int current = 1;
    int max = 1;

    var cleanPassword = password.Select(c => (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c : '\0');

    char lastChar = '\0';
    int direction = 0;
    foreach (char c in cleanPassword)
    {
        int diff = c - lastChar;
        if (Math.Abs(diff) == 1)
        {
            if (current == 1)
                direction = diff;
            if (diff == direction)
            {
                current++;
                if (current > max)
                    max = current;
            }
            else
                current = 1;
        }
        else
            current = 1;
        lastChar = c;
    }
    return max < maxCharsInOrderCount;
}
```

Comment: Смысл в алфавите как раз был, чтобы исключить цифры и спецсимволы, которые так же могут быть в пароле. В вашем варианте, как понимаю их порядок тоже будет учитываться.

Comment: @DmitryRuchin нет, не будет, с чего вы взяли? Вы ж написали, что надо только большие и маленькие буквы, я так и сделал.

Comment: @DmitryRuchin комментарии нужны, или код понятен?

Comment: Да, увидел вашу чистку от лишних символов. Но тут тогда другая проблема будет. Если изначальная строка будет: a1b2c, то он будет искать в строке abc , что неправильно.

Comment: @DmitryRuchin нет, не будет, вы неверно прочитали код, там будет `a_b_c`, где `_` это 0.

Comment: Да, всё верно. С телефона читаю, не всё сразу заметил.